# Option "type" is not defined when generating new component angular 8

Tags: angular-cli

Angular CLI: 8.0.2
Angular: 8.0.0
Trying to create new component using the angular-cli command:

```
ng generate component <componentName>.
```

Getting the error:

```
Option "type" is not defined
```

This is my angular.json file: There are 2 entries with

```
"type": "initial",
```

and

```
"type": "anyComponentStyle",
```

under "budgets". The error remain even after removing the all budget node.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "pocFlipBookPages": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/pocFlipBookPages",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", 
              //"src/assets/scss/material-dashboard.scss",
              //"src/assets/css/demo.css",
               "src/app/prifant/templatesStyles/style.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", 
              "./src/assets/prifant/turnjs/turn.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "pocFlipBookPages:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "pocFlipBookPages:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "pocFlipBookPages:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "pocFlipBookPages:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "pocFlipBookPages:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "pocFlipBookPages"
}
```

Comment: can you share your angular.json ?

Comment: @pc_coder - I added it to the question. Thanks !